# Asterisk AMI. What event fires when call begins?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I think that in my configuration does not fire this event. What event must be fired when operator answers on call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will receive a New State event with "Up" in event.State, something like:

```
Event: Newstate
Channel: Zap/2-1
State: Up
Callerid: 101
Uniqueid: 1094154427.11
```